# ActiveRecord select a string field has a certain length in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a series of Posts and would like to select all posts where its title size is lesser than 30, how to do that?

```
Posts.where("len(title) < 30")?
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This should work:

```
Post.where("length(title) < 30")
```

You're correctly using #where as shorthand for :conditions in Rails 3.  You can pass in any snippet that works in your local SQL directly.

Just remember that ActiveRecord model classes are singular by convention.

Comment: What would be the answer if i had integer instead of string example to find all the values of a column with two digits

Comment: @Pikachu-go Same question came to my mind and I tried it on an integer type column. "length(column)" works for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with MySQL:

```
Post.find(:all, :conditions => "length(title) < 30")
```